# Python pandas: Iterate over several dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have dozens of fairly similar df to which I would like to apply the same manipulations.

For example, I would like to rename cols:

```
df.rename(columns={"oldname": "newname"}, inplace=True)
```

The dataframes have all the same column names. I thought of automating like this:

```
for one_df in list_of_df:
    command = one_df + ".rename(columns={'name': 'newname'}, inplace=True)"
    exec(command)
```

Is there a more decent, panda-ish solution?

Comment: If you're using `inplace=True`, there is no need to use `exec`.  Just `one_df.rename(columns={'name': 'newname'}, inplace=True)` should work

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't, I get an error: `'str' object has no attribute 'rename'`

Comment: That's because your `list_of_df` is a list of strings?  I would've assumed it was a list of variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of comment from OP:  Let's make sure `list_of_df` is a list of dataframes and **not** a list of strings that are names of data frames.

**This**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(2, columns=list('ABC'))

list_of_df = [df1, df2]
```

**NOT THIS**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(2, columns=list('ABC'))

list_of_df = ['df1', 'df2']
```

---

If they all have the same columns, I'm inclined to keep them in one data frame.

```
df = pd.concat(dict(enumerate(list_of_df))).rename(columns={'name': 'newname'})
```

You can then access each one individually with `loc` or `xs`

```
df.loc[0]
```

or

```
df.xs(0)
```

Will return `list_of_df[0]`